# Sending and receiving RS422 data from a device

Tags: serialization, serial-port, pyserial, rs485

I have a device that uses the RS-422 communication protocol. I am struggling to connect to it to either send or read data.

There are 6 pins:

1. VCC
2. GND
3. Serial Data out A
4. Serial Data out B
5. Serial Data in A
6. Serial Data in B

- Can put it in serial mode by sending a valid message.
- Each msg/block has two parts: header and data segment.
- The segments are composed of 16-bit words, transmitted as 8-bit bytes. LSB transmitted first.

### Header

I want to request a message with the following message:

1. 81FF - Msg start
2. 0352 - msg id requested
3. 0000
4. 1000
5. 6AAF - Checksum

The above is just the header, there is no data segment (word 3 is therefore 0).

#### Word 1 (Msg start)

FFH (255 decimal). Transmitted first
81H (129 decimal). Transmitted second

### Questions

- I am using [this](https://www.amazon.de/Youmile-Konvertierungsmodul-Schnittstelle-gegenseitige-Konvertierung/dp/B07YDFQQSJ) RS485 to USB converter. Is this right?
- How do I connect the wires from the device to the reader?
- Can I request the msg using using Python and how do I do that?

Thank you

I have tried connecting the cables in different order and sending the bytes but to no avail.

Comment: "*I have a device that uses the RS-422 ... I am using this RS485 to USB converter.*" -- So you think you can use an RS-485 interface for an RS-422 connection? You're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. You need an RS-422 adapter that supports a full-duplex connection. Regardless, your hardware connection problem is off-topic for this site.